# How can I add array of addresses inside my struct. Please See the code below and help me

Tags: solidity, web3js, arrays, struct

Can anyone please update the listUser Function or make a new function to update the address of the User of type struct UserAddress.
Push it in the array in the struct User.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract Unknown {
    struct User{
        string name;
        address walletAddress;
        uint256 phoneNumber;
        UserAddress[] addresses;
        uint256 addressCount;
    }

    User[] public allUsers;
    Products[] public allProducts;

    struct Products{
        string name;
        string description;
        string price;
        string[] images;
    }

    struct UserAddress{
        string name;
        string streetName;
        string city;
        string state;
        string country;
        uint256 pincode;
    }
    
    mapping(address => User) public walletAddressToUser;
    mapping(address => Products[]) walletAddressToUserBoughtProducts;
    mapping(address => Products[]) walletAddressToUserOnSaleProducts;
    mapping(address => Products[]) ProductsInCard;

    function listUser(string memory _name, uint256 _phoneNumber) public {
        User storage user = allUsers.push();
        user.name = _name;
        user.phoneNumber= _phoneNumber;
        user.walletAddress = msg.sender;
        allUsers.push(user);
        walletAddressToUser[msg.sender] = user;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is kind of unclear. You want to  create an array of `UserAddress`es in `listUser()` and add it to your `User` struct? Short answer is, you can't do that, you'd  have to find a workaround. An obvious one would be to add an `(address => UserAddress[]) walletToAddresses;` mapping, im sure you can figure out other ones too. Exact implementation is down to you because i have no idea how you're getting that data, but if it's passed as an arg to the function you just have to copy it.

By the way, your current code is adding the `User` you're creating 2 times in the array, i assume that's not intended. Do

```js
    function listUser(string memory _name, uint256 _phoneNumber, UserAddress[] memory _addresses) public {
        User memory user;
        user.name = _name;
        user.phoneNumber= _phoneNumber;
        user.walletAddress = msg.sender;
        user.addresses = _addresses;
        allUsers.push(user);
        walletAddressToUser[msg.sender] = user;
    }
```

or

```js
    function listUser(string memory _name, uint256 _phoneNumber, UserAddress[] memory _addresses) public {
        User storage user = allUsers.push();
        user.name = _name;
        user.phoneNumber= _phoneNumber;
        user.walletAddress = msg.sender;
        user.addresses = _addresses;
        walletAddressToUser[msg.sender] = user;
    }
```

instead

Comment: Thank you @foxxxey, Ya I did push it twice by mistake sry there. I got your point. I want to know if l took all the parameters of UserAddress struct in the listuser function as an argument then how can I push it in that array of address (type UserAddress) in the user struct? Can I do it, if yes can you please show me its code. Sorry for being Unclear.